# Adjoint of an isometry maps set of extreme points onto the corresponding set to its codomain

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, proof-explanation

**Notation:**
$\phi:C_0(X) \rightarrow C_0(Y)$ is an isometry with adjoint $\phi^*:C_0(Y)^* \rightarrow C_0(X)^*$ where $C_0(X)$ is the set of complex-valued continuous functions on $X$ and $C_0(X)^*$ is the Banach space consisting bounded linear functionals on $C_0(X).$

For each $x \in X,$ denote $\mu_x$ as the positive unit mass concentrated at $x,$ that is, $\mu_x\{x\} = 1$ and $\mu_x(X \setminus \{x\}) = 0.$

In the paper '[A Generalized Banach Stone Theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2035175?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)' by Cambern, he stated the following in page $397,$ third paragraph:

> If $\phi$ maps $C_0(X)$ isometrically onto $C_0(Y),$ then its adjoint $\phi^*$ maps the set of extreme points of the unit ball of $C_0(Y)^*$ onto the corresponding set in $C_0(X)^*.$
>   Hence, for each $y \in Y,$ there exists an $x \in X$ and a complex number $\lambda$ with modulus one such that 
>   $$\phi^*\mu_y = \lambda \cdot \mu_x.$$

Question: How to show that $\phi^*$ maps set of extreme points to set of extreme points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjoint map of an isometric operator is isometric. Isometries map extreme points to extreme points.

Comment: Thanks. How to show that isometries map extreme points to extreme points?